# How do I separate a comma-separated list into two columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long, comma-separated list which looks like this in Excel:

```
401.50,0.027  
402.00,0.028  
402.50,0.029  
403.00,0.031  
403.50,0.032  
404.00,0.034  
404.50,0.037
```

Is there a simple way to convert this into two separate columns? There are over 800 values, and I am really not looking forward to separating them all individually.

Answer (score 34):

Have you tried using **Text to Columns**?

1. Highlight the column that contains your list.
2. Go to **Data** > **Text to Columns**.
3. Choose **Delimited**. Click **Next**.
4. Choose **Comma**. Click **Next**.
5. Choose **General** or **Text**, whichever you prefer.
6. Leave **Destination** as is, or choose another column. Click **Finish**.

You could also use two formulas in two separate columns.

To get the values to the left of the comma:

```
=0+LEFT(K1,FIND(",",K1)-1)
```

To get the values to the right of the comma:

```
=0+RIGHT(K1,LEN(K1)-FIND(",",K1))
```

where `K1` contains the initial string, such as `401.50,0.027`

** `0+` before the formulas converts the extracted substrings to numerical data.

Comment: After this, to convert the columns to rows, you can select the columns, then select Paste and then Transpose.

Comment: It works in Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 4):

Copy/Paste the text into a text editor
Replace all space characters with carriagereturn/linefeeds
Save as a TXT file.
Open the file in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

write a little vba to process your list

This assumes the list of values is in a single cell and is selected.  Puts the results in the following cells

```
Sub zx()
    Dim a() As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    a = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    ReDim v(1 To UBound(a) + 1, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(a) + 1
        j = InStr(a(i - 1), ",")
        v(i, 1) = Val(Left(a(i - 1), j - 1))
        v(i, 2) = Val(Mid(a(i - 1), j + 1))
    Next

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(a) + 1, 2) = v
End Sub
```